# Ошибка gradle 6.1.1

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip'.
Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for 6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66 (D:\\android\\gradle\\caches\\6.1.1\\scripts-remapped\\eclipsePlugin_ctntlon8maemn5gbrgkscidg1\\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\\cp_init3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87).
Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\4cf14c32758c39c40001aa2dc0fb4893\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.buildship.core\\init.d\\eclipsePlugin.gradle' (D:\\android\\gradle\\caches\\6.1.1\\scripts\\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\\cp_init\\cp_init3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87).
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

Танцы с бубнами по переустановке среды и всего чего можно - не дали успеха.

Ошибка появляется после добавления Application.java Рядом с MainActivity.java

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package pkgname;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}
```

**Application.java:**

```
package pkgname;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
public class Application extends FlutterApplication
        implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    CustomPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

**flutter doctor**

```
PS D:\flutter projects\loginapp> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at C:\Users\admin\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (13 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at d:\android\sdk_platform\
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\android
    • Java binary at: D:\android\sdk\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\android\sdk
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.50.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator
```

Comment: Я заметил вы делаете нативный плагин, но старого формата. Вот вам документация как сейчас все работает: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin

Comment: Нет. я добавлял существующий. Ошибка была пропала после обновления vscode,но на днях вышло новое обновление и ошибка снова появилась.

Comment: Эта ошибка никак не связанна с VSCode... Запустите на Android Studio, пусть он проанализирует проект.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I have tried many things but nothing worked Until I try following:

- Close Android Studio
- Delete any directory matching `gradle-[version]-all` within `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`. If you encounter a "File in use" error (or similar), terminate any running Java executables.
- Open Android Studio as Administrator.
- Try to sync project files.
- If the above does not work, try restarting your computer and/or delete the project's .gradle directory.
- Open the problem project and trigger a Gradle sync.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо. Пропустил. Поправлю

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your answer into Russian. This answer may get removed soon.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Тут эта заготовка не к месту, после перевода сообщения а-ля "у меня таже проблема", ответа всё равно не получится. --> Тревога "не ответ" и возможно комментерий.

Comment: @0xdb, не совсем. Я сначала тоже так подумал. Начинается оно так, да (У меня та же проблема. Перепробовал все - ничего не помогает) Но потом он пишет "Пока не попробовал следующее" и далее алгоритм действий. Поэтому это можно расценивать как ответ, наверное

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да, вы правы, предложение до конца не дочтал, сподкнулся на  >>Until<<, раз с заглавной буквы, то прочёл как фича/плагин или что-то ешё.  Спасибо!